# Etheruem: Pyethereum Error

Tags: setuptools, ethereum

After installing pyethereum I get the following error asking to upgrade my setuptools. I have upgraded setuptools but it seems my system can't still recognize it.

Here is the error I get:

```
error: Setup script exited with Your setuptools version (1.1.6) is too old to
correctly install this package. Please upgrade to a newer version (>= 3.3).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this:

```
sudo easy_install -U setuptools
```

In my case, this took me to setuptools version 25.4.0 for Python version 2.7 on my Mac, which I verified by running this:

```
sudo easy_install --version

setuptools 25.4.0 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-25.4.0-py2.7.egg (Python 2.7)
```